# How do I connect to MYSQL Docker from my Mac?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I'm going in circles trying to figure this out!

I have a remote Mac running Docker v3.5.2 and a Maria DB container.

I'd like to access the database from another Mac on my network, but I cant work it out!

I can connect just fine from the host Mac itself.

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  db:
    restart: always
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: MARIADB
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      BIND_ADDRESS: 0.0.0.0
```

I've also granted all privileges to the root user.

I have a file:

```
#/init/01.sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
```

I always get the error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'10.0.0.16' (using password: YES)
```

Any ideas! I'm going bonkers trying to figure out how to set this up! :-)

Comment: Maybe a FLUSH PRIVILEGES is necessary?

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo still no go :-(

I feel like I've had this working before though!

Comment: I can create an SSH tunnel I guess. But I just wanted to get it working if possible as it seems like it should work!

Comment: are you accessing the right port? `root@10.0.0.16:3306`

Comment: I think so, and even I am explicit in the port I still can't connect:

mysql -u root -p -h 10.0.0.17 -P 3306

Answer (score 0):

So it's working now!

I burned it all down, deleted all the existing containers and re-ran 'docker compose up'.

I'm sure I tried that already... LOL

Anyway, now it's working!